# value changed in nested child flow not reflected in main parent flow (MULE 4)

Tags: foreach, dataweave, mule4

I have declared a variable var2 outside foreach loop.

> **Usecase**:
>
> before 1st iteration value of var2="abc"
> after first iteration var2="bcd"

I want second iteration to use value as "bcd" but second iteration is using the value "abc".

Please suggest a solution for my usecase.

**UPDATE**

The issue is not due to foreach.

I have 3 flows
flow1--> flow2(childofflow1)--> flow3(childofflow2)

I defined variable vars.var2 in flow1 --> updated it in flow3 --> updated value reflected in flow2 --> updated value doesn't reflect in flow1

```
value in flow1 = a
value in flow2 = a
value updated in flow3 to b 
value reflected in flow2 = b
value reflected in flow1 = a
```

Comment: I'm confused about what the issue is.  Can you add code, xml and clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had set target variable for flow 2 that's why any change to payload/variables was not reflected in flow1.
Setting the target variable in a Flow Reference component causes the original message to remain unchanged. This means that any modification to the payload or to the variables that occur in the referenced flow revert after the referenced flow finishes executing its processors, returning the payload and variables to their original values.

Alternatively, if you do not define a target variable, any modification that occurs to the payload or to the variables in the referenced flow persist after the referenced flow finishes its execution, changing the original value of the payload or variables.

```
Documentation for reference:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/flowref-about
```

Answer (score 2):

The foreach scope actually preserves the values of variables from the previous iteration and that is documented behavior: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/for-each-scope-concept#variable-propagation

Perhaps your flow is overwriting the value.

Example:

```
        <set-variable value='abc' doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="var2"/>
        <set-payload value="#[[1,2,3]]"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" >
            <set-variable value='#[vars.var2 ++ "def"]' doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="var2"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Iteration #[vars.counter] value vars2: #[vars.var2]"/>
        </foreach>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="final value #[ vars.var2]"/>
```

Output log:

```
Iteration 1 value vars2: abcdef
Iteration 2 value vars2: abcdefdef
Iteration 3 value vars2: abcdefdefdef
final value abcdefdefdef
```

Comment: I don't want to concatenate any value to var2. I want to override it inside the loop and retrieve it in further iterations

Comment: @HMT Just remove ```vars.var2 ++``` in the set-variable component.

Comment: I just provided that example to prove that it works Each iteration updates the variables of the previous one.. Please update your question with the details of your flow to see your specific problem.

Comment: Hi Aled, I have updated my problem statement.